# Make same width of all label in visjs : Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, vis.js

I'm using visjs library (http://visjs.org/docs/network/) to show my network.

Is there any way to make width of all node equal and set margin?

In below image I want the width of 'G', 'B1', 'D1', 'A1', 'F', 'L'.

I tried using widthConstraint, shape = 'box' but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: why is angular related to this ? What about using css?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I'm using visjs library in angular code so I added angularjs. There might be a chance that some of functionalities are not added for angularjs (It's my assmption). And it generates single image file with one canvas, so not possible with CSS.

Comment: did you find any solution?